# Why is IVPN so slow?

Tags: vpn

I use [IVPN](https://www.ivpn.net) on my laptop, over Wi-Fi, with two proxies, each with just under 30ms delay. Web pages load snappily, and online gaming shows no perceptible drag.

Using it on my Android ‘phone (which probably has more processing power than my laptop), with only one of those proxies, over a 4G data link, leads to web pages taking a few seconds to load.

(How) can I improve this, as I would like to use IVPN for ***all*** traffic? Are there any settings that you can recommend? Does anyone else experience this delay?

Comment: Your 4G provider connects slowly to the VPN, I guess?

Comment: Could be, I suppose. I can contact them & ask. If so, seek another provider. My home WiFI uses a different provider, so I can compare when I get home in 6 hours or so

Comment: "which probably has more processing power than my laptop" - Note that many VPN client's are single-threaded software. A 2x2.2GHz CPU makes a faster VPN client than a 8x1.4GHz CPU, as examples.

Comment: True; don't know why I wrote that, I doubt that it plays any great role